# bash script problem with understanding how shuf works

Tags: bash

I have the following problem understanding this line of code

```
for NUMBER in $(shuf -i1-$MAX_NUMBER)
```

Do I understand correctly that I take subsequent numbers up to "$MAX_NUMBER" or the function "shuf -i1-" make any changes?

Comment: That loop is considered an **anti-pattern** see [Dont' Read Lines with For](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/DontReadLinesWithFor)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`shuf -i1-$MAX_NUMBER` prints a random permutation of the numbers in the range of 1 to `$MAX_NUMBER` (i.e, not subsequent).
This means that in each iteration of the loop, the value of `$NUMBER` will be a random value between 1 and `$MAX_NUMBER`, until all numbers have been used.